# TableViewController and Tab Views (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tabbar

I currently have a basic app where there's a list of items in a TableView and I want to adapt a tab bar underneath the TableView, where all it would do it load a different set of data onto the table. Same UI.

What would be the best way to handle this? Only thing I can think of is to create another separate controller and copy and paste the most of the code in here and direct the TabBarController to that controller.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, such as somehow creating an adapter or checking which tab is selected and then listing the data?

Sorry if I dont make any sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: UISegmentedControl is probably a better choice that a tab bar. A tab bar manages multiple view controllers. If you did want to use a tab bar, you could instantiate multiple instances of your one view controlller but supply different data, so you wouldn't need to duplicate any code.

Comment: In addition to above suggestion if you are looking for a tabbar kind of interface then you can 2 buttons at the bottom of your view controller and based on selection you can reload the table with associated datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add child controllers(for tabs) into a base controller and replace the view of base-controller from selected tab child view-controller

*This link may help you to make a custom tabbar:*
https://github.com/hollance/MHTabBarController

Answer (score 0):

Start a new Xcode project and pick Tabbed Application as your template.  That will give you your tabs and two empty view controllers.  You can either add a UITableView to those existing controllers or you can delete them both and add as many Table View Controllers as you'll need.  To attach a new controller to an existing Tab Bar Controller, you do a cntl-drag from the Tab Bar Controller to each of the new controllers.  Then pick "view controllers" as the relationship.

You can use the same view controller class for your Table View Controllers.  To differentiate the views, use the "tag" field on the View object on each Table View Controller - Give each one a different number.  Then in the generic Table View Controller code you can access that number as `view.tag()`.

Comment: FYI:  Tab View Controller can display up to 5 tabs at once - more than that and it'll give you a "More" tab.